# Are primitive arrays allowed in HashMaps?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, hash, hashmap

I'm trying to make a `HashMap` with `String` keys and `String[]` values. But when I call the `put` method and try to compile, it gives me this error:

```
cannot find symbol - method put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[])
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
    String[] options = {
        "Aside from you almost pulling my hair out, I think so.",
        "Who are you?",
        "Why can't I see anything?"};
    options.put("Hey man, are you alright?", options); //Compile time error!
```

Shouldn't this work?

Comment: `options.put();` ? `options` is the array! Where is the `HashMap`? And how do you declare it?

Comment: @songyuanyao O_o I named the HashMap 'options' too! Ok now it works. man, I feel so stupid right now XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are primitive arrays allowed in HashMaps?

Yes they are allowed<sup>1</sup>.  And `java.lang.String[]` is not a primitive array<sup>2</sup> ... but it is allowed anyway.

The problem is that you are calling `put` on `options`, and `options` is NOT a `HashMap`.  It is an array!

The error message is actually reporting that `java.lang.String[]` doesn't have a `put` method.

---

<sup>1 - Using arrays as `HashMap` keys is allowed too, but it is a bad idea.  For a start, the `hashCode` and `equals` methods on an array are not overloaded from `Object`, so key lookup will be based on object identity.</sup>

<sup>2 - A primitive array is an array of a primitive (non-reference) type.  `String` is a reference type.</sup>

Comment: I've been going over this code for hours and didn't notice that XP

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the same name for map and string array.

You need :

```
Map optionsMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
```

then

```
String[] options = {
        "Aside from you almost pulling my hair out, I think so.",
        "Who are you?",
        "Why can't I see anything?"};
optionsMap.put( "Hey man, are you alright?", options );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't this work?

Nope! You are invoking the `put()` method on a `String[]` object.

> cannot find symbol - method put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[])

In fact this is exactly the way Java is trying to tell you that xD

The code below shows how to correctly store your String array into a hash map.

```
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
String key = "Hey man, are you alright?";
String[] options = {
       "Aside from you almost pulling my hair out, I think so.",
       "Who are you?",
       "Why can't I see anything?"};
map.put(key, options);

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(map.get(key)));
```